# How can i get the data-value with what statment?

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement, button

How can i get the data-vale?

## On html file

```
<form method='get' action='#'>
                        <input type="submit" data-value="1" value="Edit" name="Type" />
                        <input type="submit" data-value="1" value="Delete" name="Type" />
```

## In django views

```
if request.GET.get('Type') == 'Delete':
    print (request.GET.get('Delete'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the `<button>` tag and specify a name-value pair:

```
<form method='get' action='#'>
    <button name="Type" value="Edit" type="submit" data-value="1">Edit</button>
    <button name="Type" value="Delete" type="submit" data-value="1">Delete</button>
</form>
```

or if you want to submit the value as well, we can do this with:

```
<form method='get' action='#'>
    <button name="Type" value="Edit-1" type="submit">Edit</button>
    <button name="Type" value="Delete-1" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

In that case we can check this in the view with:

```
if request.GET.get('Type', '').startswith('Delete'):
    __, item = request.GET['Type'].split('-', 1)
```

In that case `item` will contain the value after the hyphen.

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

Comment: But use what statement to get those value?

Comment: It will be in the `request.GET.get('Type')`, if you did not click on a button, then of course the `request.GET` will not contains a `Type`.

Comment: I still don't know how to get the data-value{ data-value="1" }, I only can get { Delete }

Comment: @onkwanon: because it is not the value, if you want to pass the value, you should specify `value="1"`, and thus *not* `delete`.

Comment: I am just thinking about how to get multi value from the button. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @onkwanon: just combine the two, for example with a hyphen, and then "unpack" these in Django, see edit.